# Given day, month, year calculate day in year

Tags: c, time

I'am finished with the first half. Validating the input. Now I need to calculate the day in year regarding my input.

My idea is to use the time.h library and somehow send my input to it and get back the given day in the year. My problem is I don't understand how it works or if my idea is working at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

```
    /* 
Uebung 2 - Kunkal Lukas
Aufgabe 1
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int dd = 0;
int mm = 0;
int yy = 0;

int main()
{ 
   printf("Bitte geben Sie ein Datum in folgenden Format ein dd.mm.yyyy: ");
   scanf("%d.%d.%d", &dd, &mm, &yy);

   //check year
   if (yy>=1900 && yy<=9999)
   {
      //check month
      if(mm>=1 && mm<=12)
      {
         //check days
         if((dd>=1 && dd<=31) && (mm==1 || mm==3 || mm==5 || mm==7 || mm==8 || mm==10 || mm==12 ))
            printf("Datum richtig!\n");
         else if((dd>=1 && dd<=30) && (mm==4 || mm==6 || mm==9 || mm==11))
            printf("Datum richtig!\n");
         else if((dd>=1 && dd<=28) && (mm==2))
            printf("Datum richtig!\n");
         else if(dd==29 && mm==2 && (yy%400==0 || (yy%4==0 && yy%100!=0)))
            printf("Datum richtig!\n");
         else
            printf("Eingabe Tag falsch.\n");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Eingabe Monat falsch.\n");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Eingabe Jahr falsch.\n");
   }
   printf("Folgendes Datum wurde eingelesen: %d.%d.%d\n", dd, mm, yy);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [`tm` structure](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html) has what you need: "`int tm_yday` Day of year [0,365].".

Comment: If you are using a system with a 32-bit `time_t` support (rather than 64-bit support), then your date range will be more limited than 1900-9999.  You can safely use 1902-2037 for whole years; the limits are reached during 1901-12-13 and 2038-01-19.

Comment: @carce-bo: every 4 years is too simple a rule for leap years, though it works for the range 1901-2099.  A leap year is a year that is divisible by 4, unless it is also divisible by 100, unless it is divisible by 400.  1996 was a leap year (divisible by 4); 1900 was not a leap year (divisible by 100); 2000 was a leap year (divisible by 400).

Comment: You can create a `struct tm` structure, and set the fields all zero: `struct tm t1 = { 0 };` and then set the `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, `tm_mday` fields carefully, noting that you have to subtract 1900 from the year and 1 from the month.  Set the `tm_isdst` field to `-1`.  Then call `mktime()` and extract the value you need from `tm_yday` (0 for 1st January to 364 or 365 for 31st December).

Comment: @pmg the page is overwhelming can you point me to a working code. I don't understand how to use this correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `struct tm` structure, and set the fields all zero:

```
struct tm t1 = { 0 };
```

and then set the `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, `tm_mday` fields carefully, noting that you have to subtract 1900 from the year and 1 from the month.  Set the `tm_isdst` field to `-1`.  Then call [`mktime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html) and extract the value you need from `tm_yday` (0 for 1st January to 364 or 365 for 31st December).

```
int day_of_year(int year, int month, int day)
{
    struct tm t1 = { 0 };
    t1.tm_year = year - 1900;
    t1.tm_mon  = month - 1;
    t1.tm_mday = day;
    t1.tm_isdst = -1;
    mktime(&t1);
    return t1.tm_yday + 1;
}
```

This returns a number 1..366 for the day of the year.  It doesn't directly validate the presented year, month, day values, but `mktime()` 'normalizes' those values.  The `mktime()` function does report errors by returning `-1`; I've ignored that.

Comment: would this work for any range of years >= 1900 ?

Comment: @carce-bo — if you're on a system with a 64-bit `time_t`, then the answer is "yes".  As I noted earlier (in a comment to the main question), if you are using a system with a 32-bit time_t support (rather than 64-bit support), then your date range will be more limited than 1900-9999. You can safely use 1902-2037 for whole years; the limits are reached during 1901-12-13 and 2038-01-19.  Going backwards in time before 1900 starts running into problems with when the country switched from Julian to Gregorian calendar, and various other idiosyncrasies.  (Run `cal 9 1752` on a Unix/Linux system.)

Comment: If you're curious, do a Google search on '`sweden february 30 1712`' — it was a real date in that one year in that country.

Comment: Oh, and Russia's October Revolution occurred in November in Europe — Russia didn't switch to the Gregorian calendar until later.  So, for Europeans, the revolution occurred on 1917-11-07 (Gregorian), but for Russians, it occurred on 1917-10-25 (Julian).  On 1918-02-14, they switched from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar, jumping from 1918-01-31 in the Julian calendar (omitting 1st to 13th February 1918).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hey there A little bit of confused. for tm_mon   why do we need subtract by 1.

Comment: Because them's the rules!  If you follow the link to `<time.h>` given in the first comment, you'll find the information: `int tm_mon – Month of year [0,11].` and 
`int tm_year — Years since 1900.`  So, as I showed, the month numbers are encoded as 0..11, not 1..12.  And the years are encoded by subtracting 1900.  At the turn of the millennium, there were quite a lot of cases where code that had printed `31/12/99` (or `12/31/99`) one day printed `01/01/100` the next.

Comment: The month encoding scheme means you can use `const char *months[] = { "Jan", "Feb", …, "Nov", "Dec" };` and then index with `months[t1.tm_mon]` to get the month name.  The difference of one pointer is nowadays a minimal saving. The year encoding scheme was convenient in the 1970s and 1980s when 2-digit years were the norm, before Y2K was considered.  It, too, is far less sensible now.